# Imagine a Clustering problem where the educational researchers would like to find clusters

Tags: machine-learning, database-design, data-science, data-mining

Imagine a Clustering problem where the educational researchers would like to find clusters of students (the group of students) who have similar correlation patterns when it comes to the correlation of their GPA vs Income of their parents. And you are hired as the Data Scientist to do the job. 
What kind of Objective Function would you design?

Why?

Please use your own reasoning and explain in detail.

Comment: "Please use your own reasoning and explain in detail."

Answer (score 0):

In a recent research, a PSO was implemented to classify students under unknown number of groups. I think that all you need is the specific research.

The paper is: Forming automatic groups of learners using particle swarm optimization for applications of differentiated instruction